# How to parse multi-level JSON array?

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, powershell-5.0

Here is my Data.json. It has multi-level array. I must get all array elements:

```json
{
  "host": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dlls": [
    {
      "files": [
        {
          "path": ".\\Xml.dll",
          "store": ".\\DX\\OpenXml.dll"
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\Xml.dll",
          "store": ".\\DX\\OpenXml.dll"
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\Xml.dll",
          "store": ".\\DX\\OpenXml.dll"
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\Xml.dll",
          "store": ".\\DX\\OpenXml.dll"
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\Xml.dll",
          "store": ".\\DX\\OpenXml.dll"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "json": [
        {
          "path": ".\\index.json",
          "store": ".\\DX\\index.json"
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\index.json",
          "store": ".\\DX\\index.json"        
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\index.json",
          "store": ".\\DX\\index.json"        
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\index.json",
          "store": ".\\DX\\index.json"        
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\index.json",
          "store": ".\\DX\\index.json"        
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\index.json",
          "store": ".\\DX\\index.json"        
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In my current PS script, I can only iterate one level:

```bsh
$json = $null;
$jsonparsed = $null;
$validJson = $false;
try {
    $json = Get-Content -Raw $file; 
    $jsonparsed = ConvertFrom-Json $json -ErrorAction Stop;
    $validJson = $true;
} catch {
    $validJson = $false;
}

if ($validJson) {
    Write-Host "Provided text has been correctly parsed to JSON";
    Write-Host $jsonparsed;
} else {
    Write-Host "Provided text is not a valid JSON string" -ForegroundColor "Red";
    return;
}
```

I have to parse all JSON array element. Retrieve the value of each "path" and "store". Please te me how can I do it in PowerShell version 5. I found solutions by loading third-party assembly. But I'm not allowed to use any external assembly. Is it parseable without external assembly?

Comment: Doesn't `ConvertFrom-Json` return a `PSCustomObject`?  Just parse the members.

Comment: What output do you expect instead?

Comment: Are you looking for this: `$jsonparsed | flatten`, see: Flatten-Object: https://powersnippets.com/flatten-object/

Comment: Umm... what exactly is your question here? Parsing JSON is done with `ConvertFrom-Json` since PowerShell v3 IIRC. That hasn't changed in v5. Are you experiencing a problem? If so, please describe the behavior you expect and what (exactly) doesn't work that way.

Comment: If I try Write-Output $jsonparsed.host; I can see the value assíeted with the host key as http://localhost:5000. Same If I try Write-Output $jsonparsed.dlls; 
files                                                                                                                                             
-----                                                                                                                                             
{@{path=.\Xml.dll; store=.\DX\OpenXml.dll}, @{path=.\Xml.dll; store=.\DX\OpenXml.dll}

Comment: I want to access each path and store. Something like  $jsonparsed.dlls.files.path give me associated value e.g :  .\\Xml.dll

Comment: Simply I want to traverse all keys and values in this multi-level json array.

Comment: I fail to see what's stopping you from doing just that. Please explain in more detail what you want to achieve. In what way do you want to "traverse" the data structure? What values do you want to extract (i.e. what should the resulting data structure(s) look like)?

Comment: `$jsonparsed.dlls.files.path[0]` works fine for me. If that doesn't work for you, I presume there is something wrong with your json file.

Comment: @iRon `$jsonparsed.dlls.files[0].path` would be more accurate, although `$jsonparsed.dlls.files.path[0]` should work too in PowerShell v3 or newer, due to member enumeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you paste this into a PowerShell (v5) window:

```
$jsonparsed = convertFrom-Json @'
{
  "host": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dlls": [
    {
      "files": [
        {
          "path": ".\\Xml.dll",
          "store": ".\\DX\\OpenXml.dll"
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\Xml.dll",
          "store": ".\\DX\\OpenXml.dll"
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\Xml.dll",
          "store": ".\\DX\\OpenXml.dll"
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\Xml.dll",
          "store": ".\\DX\\OpenXml.dll"
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\Xml.dll",
          "store": ".\\DX\\OpenXml.dll"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "json": [
        {
          "path": ".\\index.json",
          "store": ".\\DX\\index.json"
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\index.json",
          "store": ".\\DX\\index.json"        
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\index.json",
          "store": ".\\DX\\index.json"        
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\index.json",
          "store": ".\\DX\\index.json"        
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\index.json",
          "store": ".\\DX\\index.json"        
        },
        {
          "path": ".\\index.json",
          "store": ".\\DX\\index.json"        
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
'@

Write-Host $jsonparsed.host
ForEach ($dll in $jsonparsed.dlls) {
    ForEach ($file in $dll.files) {
        Write-Host $file.path
        Write-Host $file.store
    }
    ForEach ($json in $dll.json) {
        Write-Host $json.path
        Write-Host $json.store
    }
}
```

You should get this:

```
.\Xml.dll
.\DX\OpenXml.dll
.\Xml.dll
.\DX\OpenXml.dll
.\Xml.dll
.\DX\OpenXml.dll
.\Xml.dll
.\DX\OpenXml.dll
.\Xml.dll
.\DX\OpenXml.dll
.\index.json
.\DX\index.json
.\index.json
.\DX\index.json
.\index.json
.\DX\index.json
.\index.json
.\DX\index.json
.\index.json
.\DX\index.json
.\index.json
.\DX\index.json
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't work. It doesn't even go inside the ForEach top-level  loop ForEach ($dll in $jsonparsed.dlls) . So I don't see anything

Comment: I pasted the code from @iRon into a new PowerShell window and it works perfectly fine.